# Проблема встроенных свг тегов в ссылки Ie11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

верстаю сайт, дошло дело до отладки верстки в ie11 и тут совсем что то не понятное...
Свг обернутые в ссылку работают очень странно. Например на первой картинке, сразу при заходе на сайт и доскрола до блока картина вот такая
[image: картинка номер 1]

Если навестись на ссылку(ссылка это вся карточка)  картина такая картинка 2 и 3[image: ховер на самой левой][image: ховер на той что посередине]

если убрать ховер картина такая [[image: убрал ховер4]

В чём может быть проблема? На этих местах стралочки свгшные я на них при ховере вешаю анимацию вот такую[image: анимация] стили выглядят вот так[image: стиль ссылки в которую обернуто свг][image: стиль свг]
разметка вот[image: разметка]

Comment: В IE надо избегать использование svg и png (<ie9).
Для IE больше подходят jpeg и gif.

Comment: Я подключил полифилы для свг, да и верстаю только под ie11. Есть ещё какие-нибудь идеи с чем это связанно? Кстати это не единственное свг в разметке, в остальном все свг корректно отображаются даже если в ссылках

Comment: Нашёл в чём была проблема, box-shadow на карточке вызывал такой эффект,тогда встречный вопрос почему так?

Comment: Ну как? IE11 вышел в 2013 году, тогда про поддержку svg могли объявить мало какие браузеры